# Echo contents of for loop automatically

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, for

I often use a for loop to i.e. convert a bunch of file formats. In some cases, where text transformations or variables occur, it would be nice to check if the substitutions were performed correctly.

```
for i in *; do convert $i ${i%jpg}png; done
```

Is there an easy way to show the performed command? Following the example above, something along the lines of:

```
convert image1.jpg image1.png
  # command output
convert image2.jpg image2.png
  # command output
  # ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set -x
for file in *jpg; do
    convert "${file}" "${file%jpg}png"
done
set +x
```

Setting the `-x` shell option will display each executed command as it is set to be executed after all parameter expansions are completed.  `+x` undoes this.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing, I also use the `xtrace` option (set with `set -x` / `set -o xtrace` / `setopt xtrace` / `options[xtrace]=on`...), but in a subshell:

```
(set -x; for f (*.jpg) convert -- $f $f:r.png)
```

(that also makes job control cleaner, and incidently avoids polluting the environment with that `$f` variable).

To set an option locally without creating a subshell, you can also use an anonymous function and the `localoptions` option.

```
(){ set -o localoptions -x; for f (*.jpg) convert -- $f $f:r.png; }
```

(and throw in a `local f`  for that `$f` to be local to that anonymous function).

```
for f (*.jpg) (set -x; convert -- $f $f:r.png)
```

Would make it a bit less verbose (and save one process).

In the case of ImageMagick image conversion however, you can just do:

```
$ mogrify -verbose -format png -- *.jpg
a.jpg JPEG 3264x1836 3264x1836+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.07201MiB 0.050u 0:00.053
a.jpg=>a.png JPEG 3264x1836 3264x1836+0+0 8-bit sRGB 7.69297MiB 2.680u 0:02.640
b.jpg JPEG 3264x1836 3264x1836+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.07201MiB 0.060u 0:00.050
b.jpg=>b.png JPEG 3264x1836 3264x1836+0+0 8-bit sRGB 7.69297MiB 2.650u 0:02.617
```